# xcode tab bar customizable

Tags: iphone, xcode

I was wondering if there is  a tutorial or any hints for this tab bar customization, when you select  a tab bar and hold you can change the icons to user liking sort of like this (check the bottom).
[TAB] http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/

Answer (score 0):

Use **UIGestures**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];  


    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
   // UIlongtapGusture alloc and add it to  viewController1


    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];  
    // UIlongtapGusture alloc and add it to  viewController2

    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];    
   // UIlongtapGusture alloc and add it to  viewController3

    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];  
     // UIlongtapGusture alloc and add it to  viewController4


    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, 

                                     viewController2, 

                                     viewController3, 

                                     viewController4, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;  


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

see the [customization of the tab-bar here](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-tab-bar-using-ios-5-appearance-api/)